# prioritizing partitions / task execution in spark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, distribution, partitioning

I have a spark job with skewed data. The data needs to be partitioned based on a column. I would like to tell spark to start processing the biggest partitions first so that I get to use the available resources more efficiently.

The reasoning would go as follows: I have 10000 partitions in total of which 9999 partitions take just 1 minute to process and 1 partition that takes 10 minutes to process. If I get the heavy partition first I can do the job in 11 minutes if I get it as last it would take 18 minutes.

Is there a way to prioritize partitions? Does this make sense to you?

I sketched the two scenarios on a spreadsheet[image]

Answer (score 6):

Your reasoning is correct afa: if the big task were started immediately then your overall job will finish ealier.  But it's also true that you can not control the ordering (/prioritization) of the tasks  - since the spark task scheduler does not provide an interface to define that ordering.

Answer (score 1):

Long-running tasks often a result of skewed data. The right solution here 
is to re-partition your data to ensure even distribution among tasks.

```
1.Evenly distribute your data using repartition as said by @Chandan
2.There might be encounter network issues while dealing with skewed data 
where an executor’s heartbeat times out.In such cases, consider increasing
your **spark.network.timeout** and **spark.executor.heartbeatInterval**.
```

Important suggestion look for data locality level. The locality level, as far as I know, indicates which type of access to data has been performed. When a node finishes all its work and its CPU become idle, Spark may decide to start other pending task that require obtaining data from other places. So ideally, all your tasks should be process local as it is associated with lower data access latency.

You can configure the wait time before moving to other locality levels using:

```
spark.locality.wait
```

1.Spark official docs on [data locality](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/tuning.html#data-locality)

2.Explanation on data locality [refer](https://jaceklaskowski.gitbooks.io/mastering-apache-spark/spark-data-locality.html)

Answer (score 0):

if your data is skewed i.e majority of your data exists in single partition and your data is not equally divided across all the partitions.In such case you cannt make the best use of spark parallelizm.

*I have 10000 partitions in total of which 9999 partitions take just 1 minute to process and 1 partition that takes 10 minutes to process. If I get the heavy partition first I can do the job in 11 minutes if I get it as last it would take 18 minutes.*

It does not work like that. Each partition will be taken up for execution by only one task or thread.So in your case all other tasks get completed and only task will take time to complete due to data skewness.

Way to handle and speed up the process.

1. Evenly distribute your data

   For example if you dont have any partitioning key then add a new column as *sequence number%numberOfpartitionsyouwant* to your dataframe. For example if you want 10 partitions then

numberOfpartitionsyouwant = 10

so each data will be partitioned between numbers 0 to 9. Then partitionBy the new dataframe using this new column.

Comment: Thing is I need all the data with a given value for the partitioning column on a single executor. So I can partition more but data will stay skewed. I want just the tasks associated with bigger partition to be allocated first.

Comment: how will it help you if it will be allocated first. In spark each task will be assigned to only one partition. If you use one executor with 4 cores then 4 threads will take 4 partitions. One partition won’t be allocated to multiple threads or tasks

Comment: Well with 4 executors that won't matter much, with a thousand though...